# Output a Laravel variable within a javascript template

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-4

I am working on a `Laravel-4` application and I am using `javascript templates` to render items on a particular page. Below is my template for my slideshow items

```
<script type="t/template" id="bookItem">
        <div class="resource-wrap" data-resource="@{{=type}}">
            <div class="resource @{{=type}}">
                @{{id}}
                <div class="image">
                @foreach($slideshow->find($slideshow->id)->slides()->take(1)->get() as $slide)
                    <img width="100%" height="100%" src="/img/slideshows/{{$slide->link}}"/>
                @endforeach
                </div>
                @{{/id}}
                <ul class="info">
                    <li class="title"><a href="#">@{{=id}}@{{=title}}@{{=name}}</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">@{{=desc}}</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a class="ov open-@{{=type}}" href="#"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
</script>
```

It is rendering alright on the page and everything is working correctly except for one thing. This line:

```
@foreach($slideshow->find($slideshow->id)->slides()->take(1)->get() as $slide)
```

I am trying to pass in the id of the current item but cannot seem to do so. I can here:

```
<li class="title"><a href="#">@{{=id}}@{{=title}}@{{=name}}</a></li>
```

But when I use `@{{=id}}` in my loop I get an error. I am wondering how I can print this variable out in the loop?

Comment: The line `$slideshow->find($slideshow->id)` doesn't make much sense at all.. If you can do `$slideshow->id`, you don't need `->find()`, assuming we are talking about Eloquent model here.

Comment: Also the line `@foreach($slideshow->find($slideshow->id)->slides()->take(1)->get() as $slide)` doesn't make much sense, if you only take 1 item, what sense does `@foreach` make?

Answer (score 0):

I tend to try to avoid querying in the view and query within the controller, passing the collection to the view - makes it cleaner in the view. Keep the view separate as much as possible

So assuming you have passed a variable `$slideshow` which is your collection you can then do:

```
            <div class="image">
            @foreach($slideshow AS $slide)
                <img width="100%" height="100%" src="/img/slideshows/{{$slide->link}}"/>
            @endforeach
            </div>
```

I'm not clear what value $id relates to in your question. Is that the id of the slide? if it is then as long as it's contained in the loop you can get that by $slide->id

If assumption is wrong can you confirm what id relates to